# Regexp to validate ip address with last digit as non zero

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, angular-forms

I have a regex that i ended up using from one of the answer here in SO . 
Basically my regex must validate ipv4 address with mask .

So i ended up using the below regex :

`(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)/([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-2]|(((128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0\.0\.0)|(255\.(0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0\.0)|(255\.255\.(0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0)|(255\.255\.255\.(0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254))))`

Now my challenge is to not allow 0 in the last digit of ip i.e ,
`192.168.6.10/mask` is valid but `192.168.6.0/mask` is invalid

So i modified the above regexp to something like this :

`(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]?)/([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-2]|(((128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0\.0\.0)|(255\.(0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0\.0)|(255\.255\.(0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0)|(255\.255\.255\.(0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254))))`

but `192.168.6.0` is always valid when testing with Angular `Validators.pattern`

Any idea where i'm going wrong ?

**EDIT**
List of IPs & its validity :

192.168.6.6/24 is valid 
192.168.6.6/24 is valid
192.168.6.24/24 is valid

192.168.6.0/24 invalid
192.168.6.0/255.255.255.0 is invalid

Comment: Can you provide a list of valid and invalid IPs?

Comment: @Gurman have added them

Comment: Your current regex [does not work](https://regex101.com/r/tozH95/1), or match anything.  Voting to close as a typo question.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/WlGflm/2

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen here is a stackblitz example for the working of the validation : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng6f3s

Comment: I have one doubt: is `192.168.6.1/255.255.255.0` valid?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is valid

Comment: Then [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54514999/3832970) is what you need. Tested at StackBlitz (however, I cannot save the fiddle :().

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i'll try it. Thanks for the help and example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to avoid matching any IP with the  last octet set to `0`.

You may use

```
ipAddress : FormControl = new FormControl('' , Validators.pattern(/^(?!(?:\d+\.){3}0(?:\/|$))(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\/(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-2]|(?:(?:128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0\.0\.0|255\.(?:0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0\.0|255\.255\.(?:0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0|255\.255\.255\.(?:0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254)))$/));
```

Here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TjNNhR/1)

The main addition is the lookahead after `^` that is executed once at the start of a string. The `(?!(?:\d+\.){3}0(?:\/|$))` pattern is a *negative* lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location (string start), there are:

- `(?:\d+\.){3}` - three repetitions of 1+ digits and a dot
- `0` - a zero
- `(?:\/|$))` - `/` or (`|`) end of string (`$`).

Notice I defined the pattern using a *regex literal notation* (`/regex/`) and I had to add `^` (string start) and `$` (string end) anchors since the regex was no longer anchored by default. Also, to escape special chars in a regex literal notation, you only need one backslash, not two.

Comment: i tried using this but it actually fails for all the ips i enter . updated the example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ebwa4

Comment: @CruelEngine Before you go on the further journey with regex, please read [Creating a regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_regular_expression)

Comment: apologies , i was messing around with my example . i have removed the `''` and now the exp is working . Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the last part cannot be written `000` and `00` but just `0`. Then you can you such regex

```
^(?:(?:2(?:5[0-5]|[0-4]\d)|1?\d?\d)\.){3}(?:(?:2(?:5[0-5]|[0-4]\d)|1?\d\d|[1-9]))$
```

Where diff between the first groups and the last one that one-digit value should be from 1 to 9

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/WlGflm/3)

Comment: this will work without the mask . upvoting the answer for someone looking for validations without mask. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this pattern

`^(?:[1-9]|[0-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(?:[1-9]|[0-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(?:[1-9]|[0-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(?:2[0-5][1-5]|[1-9]|1[0-9][1-9]|[1-9][1-9])$`

Online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/WlGflm/1/)

For the last numbers you have check with this

`(?:2[0-5][1-5]|[1-9]|1[0-9][1-9]|[1-9][1-9])`

Comment: i'll try this . Thanks for the answer

Comment: this fails for ip address for last set if it is something like this :``60.243.33.90``

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach here is simple, and just involves adding a negative lookbehind at the very end of the pattern `(?<!\.0)`, which asserts that `.0` is not the immediately preceding term in the IP address.  Applying this to your correctly working pattern from the comments above, we get:

```
^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}
    (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\/
    ([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-2]|(((128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0\.0\.0)|
    (255\.(0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0\.0)|
    (255\.255\.(0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0)|
    (255\.255\.255\.(0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254))))(?<!\.0)$
```

### Demo

The downside is that your JavaScript engine may not yet support negative lookbehind syntax just yet.